# Why do I need to cabal install cabal-install in every new sandbox?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Every time I make a new cabal sandbox and run `cabal update` to get the latest package list, I'm prompted about the availability of a new version of cabal. So I install it in the sandbox using `cabal install cabal-install`.

I think to myself, I should install this new version globally too, outside of the sandbox. So I leave the sandbox and `cabal install cabal-install` again.

I expected that this would carry over to the next new sandbox, but it doesn't. Is there any way to make it carry over to save the time of reinstalling it in every new sandbox?

Comment: The sandbox is exactly that. It contains no versions of anything. This is what gives it it's strength.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the updated version?

Comment: @Stefan, in fact according to `cabal --version` I'm not running the updated version. How'd that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `cabal` via `cabal install cabal-install` globally results in a new binary in your home folder in `~/.cabal`.

As long as this path is not included in `$PATH`, the default installed `cabal` from e.g. `/usr/bin` will get executed, which will result in the warning of a new available version.